# Auxiliary fields in non-supersymmetric theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, supersymmetry, superspace-formalism

It is well-known, that in superspace formulation of supersymmetric theories auxiliary fields appear. In present of such fields SUSY transformations are linear and independent of model.

Are some non-supersymmetric examples of such phenomena?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Could you make the question more precise? What would stop someone from introducing as many auxiliary field sectors as they want?

Comment: @Qmechanic, Essense in this "In present of such fields SUSY transformations are linear and independent of model" statement. Fields must be relevant for some symmetry.

Comment: @Qmechanic, will these fields make transformation laws simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Auxiliary fields are useful to make certain algebras close off-shell, for example the supersymmetric algebra. Another famous example is the BRST algebra, namely $Q_{B}^{2}=0$. It might not close off-shell.

If you want to do deformations on the action principle it is interesting to hold those algebras off-shell. This allow you to do deformations while preserving the algebra in a easy way.

The fact that algebras might not close off-shell can be traced back to the fact that they are mixing fields with first order derivatives and fields with second order derivatives in the action.